# Restsharp: Thread is running or terminated; it cannot restart error when using httpclient inside loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, restsharp

I am trying to use RESTSHARP https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp to POST to an API and check its status after the call:

```
private static bool AddTenant(string tenantName)
{
    var client = new RestClient("http:\\localhost\api");
    var request = new RestRequest("addtenant", Method.POST);
    request.AddParameter("tenant_name", tenantName);
    var response = client.Execute(request);

    var addTenantResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AddTenantResponse>(response.Content);

    // check the status of the api call, inital status is PENDING
    var ctr = 0;
    while (addTenantResponse .Status != "SUCCESS" && ctr < 10)
    {
        client = new RestClient("http:\\localhost\api");
        request = new RestRequest("apicallstatus", Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("X-Apikey",  "testing");
        request.AddParameter("job_id", addTenantResponse.JobId);
        response = client.Execute(request);
        addTenantResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiStatusResponse>(response.Content);

        if (addTenantResponse .Status == "FAILURE")
        {
            break;
        }

        //Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
        ctr++;
    }

    return addTenantResponse .Status == "SUCCESS"
}

[Serializable]
public class ApiStatusResponse
{
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Job_ID")]
    public string JobId { get; set; }

    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

I am creating new instance of RestClient in the successive calls to check the status of the api call I was wondering if this causes this thread related error:

> System.Threading.ThreadStateException: Thread is running or
> terminated; it cannot restart.    at
> System.Threading.Thread.StartupSetApartmentStateInternal()    at
> System.Threading.Thread.Start(StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
> System.Threading.Thread.Start()

I tried putting Task.Delay between the api calls but it doesn't help. Any idea what is causing this issue?

Comment: Why Task.Delay? Why not Thread.Sleep? I don't see anything that suggests you r running any tasks

Comment: Are you trying to call this method in parallel or something ? Also, there is really no need to use RestSharp these days, use the more modern `IHttpClientFactory`

Comment: @TheGeneral no, this is synchronous operation. I'll try thread.sleep suggestion. Thanks for Ihttpclientfactory suggestion though ill have a look too.

Comment: Even if i put thread.sleep(1000), i still get the thread is running exception. I wonder what its cause? im creating HttpClient instance inside the loop.